# Count elements inside a json array in go

Tags: json, go

I have following example json:

```
{
    "someObjects": [
    {
        "value1": "something here"
    },
    {
        "value1": "something else"
    }
    ]
}
```

I want to count the amount of objects inside the "someObjects" array in golang without using any lib.

The json is there in a string and I do not have the corresponding struct lying around (since it is actually pretty big).
How can I count this?

Comment: Without any lib? Go is not like JavaScript, it doesn't have __native__ JSON support.  If you don't want to use libs you'll have to parse the JSON yourself.

Comment: This is done by a bit of programming. What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Why?. Note that the Go stdlib has tools to unmarshal JSON. Using a clever adhoc data structure might be a sensible first approach in which case this is some 20 lines of simple code.

Comment: you can use the reflection standard package. Try to read more about it in this [link](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect) this package lets you to manipulate objects with the arbitrary type `interface{}` (in recents versions now is called `any` type). Remember an important thing, golang is a strictly static typed language so the most easy way to do this is over an struct created by yourself and pass it to any of the functions in the json package that lets you unmarshal json's in structs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [golang json unmarshal part of map\[string\]interface{}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23249436/golang-json-unmarshal-part-of-mapstringinterface)

Answer (score 0):

Not even standard library ? Then you have to parse whatever coming from the network yourself which you can do using reflections in Go. But even in that case you have to use "reflect" package.

Comment: Of course I meant the standard lib is fine. Im sorry.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).